# Elixir Calculete sum of tuples

Tags: elixir

I have some code where i need to calculate the `sum` of `tuples` that are returned in a `list`. How could i achieve that?

```
def calc_points(hand) do
    Enum.map(hand, fn x -> String.at(x,0) end)
    |> Enum.map( fn x ->
      cond do
      x == "J" -> {2}
      x == "Q" -> {3}
      x == "K" -> {4}
      x == "A" -> {1}
      true -> case Integer.parse(x) do
        {num, ""} -> {num}
        {_, rest} -> {:error, :unparsable}
        {:error} -> {:error, :unparsable}
      end
      end
    end)
  end
```

The `input` value is `["6 of spades", "6 of suites"]` and the `output` i'm getting with this code is `[{6}, {6}]`.
How could i sum the value up to 12? with the code that i already have? Or is it needed to refactor the code?

Comment: This code does not process tens or processes them improperly.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thank you for your reply, i'll fix the bug and update the code

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up changing `{num, ""} -> {num}` line to `{num, ""} -> num`
That way it returns me a `list` of values and i ended up using `|>` to pass it to `Enum.sum()` to calculate the `sum`

**EDIT 2**

I've ended up with this code solution

```
 def calc_points(hand) do
    Enum.map(hand, fn x -> String.split(x) end)
    |> Enum.map(fn x -> Enum.at(x, 0) end)
    |> Enum.map( fn x ->
      cond do
        x == "J" -> 2
        x == "Q" -> 3
        x == "K" -> 4
        x == "Ace" -> 1
        true -> case Integer.parse(x) do
          {num, ""} -> num
          {_, rest} -> {:error, :unparsable}
          {:error} -> {:error, :unparsable}
        end
      end
    end)
    |> Enum.reduce(0,fn x,acc when is_number(x) ->
      x+acc
      _, acc -> acc
    end)
  end
```